# iOS uncaught exception isKindOfClass:NSArray.class

Tags: ios

I have been getting the below error while running my project in xcode 6.1.1, Can any please help to know what workarounds can be done to remove the below error.

[ERROR]  Uncaught Exception: Invalid parameter not satisfying: [arguments isKindOfClass:NSArray.class]
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Thanks
djrecker

Comment: Can you provide a sample project to debug? An error message is not enough.

Comment: Nope i cannot provide sample project as its happeing on my current working code, not sure if i can replicate in a sample code source, Also looks to me like a iOS issue so was thinking anyone from iOS backgroup can assist.

Comment: You're not providing any code, so you're making helping you real hard.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: What you are asking now is exactly like if you wanted us to help you repair you car telling us "it won't start" but don't let us see the car. We can't help you if we can't see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see something similar to this once in a blue moon. Have you tried cleaning the project? (In the menu: Product->Clean

Unfortunately I don't know what causes it (and I've been too lazy to attempt tracking it down), but that always clears it up for me when I see it.